# Make 2 buttons with variable content the same size Android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying in a constraint layout to make two buttons take the same size as the one with more text.

This is what I have
[image]

This is what I want
[image]

Playing with the height attribute of the buttons, setting it to "0" you can get one button to follow the other, but the other does not do the same

here is the code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tools_ly_first_buttons"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_bubble_answer_buttons"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_bubble_answer_buttons"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tools_btn_1"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tools_btn_1"
                    tools:visibility="visible">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/tools_btn_1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_round_confirmation_yes"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_regular"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:padding="@dimen/padding_bubble_answer_buttons_text"
                        tools:text="Perfect asdasdas."
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tools_btn_2"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tools_ly_first_buttons"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tools_ly_first_buttons"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/tools_btn_2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_round_confirmation_yes"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_regular"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:padding="@dimen/padding_bubble_answer_buttons_text"
                        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tools_btn_1"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        tools:text="Perfect Perfect square trition. Perfect Perfect square trition. Perfect Perfect square trition. Perfect Perfect square trition. Perfect Perfect square trition. Perfect Perfect square trition." />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by wrapping the two buttons into a `LinearLayout` (or another `ConstraintLayout`) and setting their heights both to `match_parent` while setting the height of the container view to `wrap_content`.

If your `ConstraintLayout` is already a container to be nested in other views, than the extra nesting is not necessary. Just set the button heights to `match_parent` and they will fill the container.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Short Text"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRight"
            android:text="Long Text Taking Up Many Many Many Lines of Space and More than One Line Definitely"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's what this produces - doesn't matter which button has the long text.

[image: example layout]

**Note**
In the XML you shared, the parent `ConstraintLayout` appears to be constrained to one of its child views (`tools_btn_1`). This is probably not valid.